# Make all words lowercase and the first letter of each word uppercase

Tags: php, string, title-case, ucfirst

I have a string with improper capitalization scattered like below:

```
$str = "tHis iS a StRinG thAt NeEds ProPer CapiTilization";
$newStr = ucfirst($str);
echo $newStr;
```

How would I be able to capitalize the first letter of each word and lower case the incorrectly capitalized letters?  I need the string to be fully title case.

I know I can change to lower and then use `ucwords()` but is there a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How would I be able to capitalize the first letter of each word and lower case the incorrectly capitalized letters?

[`ucwords()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) will capitilize the first letter of each word. You can combine it with [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to first lowercase everything.

For example:

```
ucwords(strtolower('HELLO WORLD!')); // Hello World!
```

Answer (score 2):

There is [an earlier question where I have already suggested `mb_convert_case()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68758674/2943403), but the sample text in that question is rather lackluster.

There is a single, native function that performs title-casing on multiple words in a string and it is multibyte-safe. This is an excellent solution because you don't need to prepare the string to be all lowercase before making the leading letter of all words uppercase.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gJck1))

```
$string = "tHis iS a StRinG thAt NeEds ProPer CapiTilization";
echo mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
```

Output:

```
This Is A String That Needs Proper Capitilization
```

---

Laravel also offers a helper method that can be used: `title()`.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$converted = Str::of('a nice title uses the correct case')->title();

// A Nice Title Uses The Correct Case
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-title

Comment: Great answer. The last argument is optional and should not be specified most of the time.

Comment: Is it the default?  I didn't check.  I just checked -- the default is `null`.

Comment: The default is null, and it will then pick up the internal encoding, which by default is UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with two functions [ucwords()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) and [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

```
<?php
    $str = "tHis iS a StRinG thAt NeEds ProPer CapiTilization";
    $newStr = ucwords(strtolower($str));
    echo $newStr;
?>
```

**Explanation:**

`strtolower()` will make all your string to lower cased.

Now, applying `ucwords()` on resulting string will make first letter of every world capital which will produce the required output.