# Have key value in associative array be uppercase first letter and the rest of the string lowercase

Tags: php, arrays, string, uppercase, lowercase

I have declared an associative array in php and assigned it key values that have a mixture of lower and uppercase letters. I need the key values in the array to be uppercase first and string the rest of the way and it needs to be in a foreach loop.

```
$city=array('Peter'=>'LEEDS',
            'Kat'=>'bradford',
            'Laura'=>'wakeFIeld');
print_r($city);
echo '<br />';

foreach($city as $name => $town) {
   
   $town = ucfirst($town);
   $town = strtolower($town);
   print_r($city);      
   
}
```

Comment: Just a quick heads up, the names - "Peter", "Kat", "Laura", these are the *keys*. The cities, "LEEDS", "bradford", "wakeFIeld", these are the *values*. There isn't such a thing as "key values" :)

Comment: This question is Unclear because you have not clearly explained the logic, nor included the exact desired output.  I don't know if you want [`$city[$name] = mb_convert_case($town, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768405/2943403).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to lowercase the key first, than use ucfirst. Your code will be like this:

```
$city = array ( "Peter" => "LEEDS", "Kat" => "bradford", "Laura" => "wakeFIeld");
print_r ( $city);
echo "<br />";

foreach ( $city as $key => $value)
{
  $city[$key] = ucfirst ( strtolower ( $value));
}
print_r ( $city);
```

Comment: this doesn't work it is still returning the key values the same way as i declared in the original city array

Comment: You declared cities as values, and people name as key. This code will change the city name (the value of the array key).

Comment: Make sure you're setting `$city[$key] = ucfirst ( strtolower ( $value));` like in this example. In your original code, your loop creates a proper town name, assigns it to `$town`, but never actually overwrites the old value, that's why it's still the same. In this example Ernani is setting `$city[$key]` explicitly to the new value

Comment: ah okay i understand sorry i got confused. yes this code is working now and i have marked it as correct. apologies i am still new to php and still getting to grips with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, but your calls to `ucfirst()` and `strtolower()` are the wrong way round...

```
$town = strtolower($town);
$town = ucfirst($town);
```

This converts it all to lower case and then upper cases the first letter.

Or to abbreviate it a bit

```
$town = ucfirst(strtolower($town));
```

You also need to alter your `foreach()` to allow it to update the town...

```
foreach($city as $name => &$town) {
```

Add the `&` to allow it to update the town.  Also move your last

```
print_r($city);
```

out of the loop.

Comment: This doesn't work still returns the same output as when i originally declared the city array